# Python case insensitive or sensitive strings as input

Tags: python, string, case-insensitive

I have the following script:

```
ip = input('Enter your string: ')
if 'tree' in ip:
   print('Correct string')
```

I would like to print 'Correct string' even if the user input is 'TREE' or 'tree' based on the case. How do I do that (optimally rather than using else or elif)?

If the input from the user is 'TREE' then the script should give an output:

```
CORRECT STRING
```

If the input from the user is 'tree' then the script should give an output:

```
correct string
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Side note: If you use the ``in`` operator, it will also match ``street`` for example, because ``street`` contains ``tree``.

Comment: you can't do that without an `if-else`. and what if user inputs `tREe`, `trEE`, `TrEE`?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the user input to lower case as:

```
ip = input('Enter your string: ').lower()
if 'tree' in ip:
   print('Correct string')
```